# jQuery css coloring won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am practicing jQuery, but I can't seem to fix the CSS background. 
I'm trying to make like this but with different color:

> http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Here is my fiddle:

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/HAZ3n/

Only jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).css({
        background-color: '#000'
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

I've tried to change the position too but same result, it won't load I think?

**EDIT:** Version: jQuery 1.9.1 jQuery UI 1.9.2

Comment: Simple rule with setting css values with jQuery - either put the property name in quotes (single or double), or use camelcase, with the first character lowercase, so `backgroundColor` in this case.

Comment: Incidentally, why on earth would you want to change the background colour for this with jQuery?  Unless you're going to be changing it often then it would make much more sense to just do it in css.

Comment: if I can change the background, I can change everything in every div with jQuery

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should.  Like I said, unless you plan to change it reactively or often then you should use css.  It would probably still make more sense to use css and add/remove classes to suit your needs, but this one simple change should not be done in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#sortable" ).css({
   'background-color': '#000'
})
```

You simply forgot to put quotes on your property. You don't need to pass over a map/object to set only one property. You can just put pass it as string.

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wPENZ/)

Comment: this syntax is going to ... me:p

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sortable" ).css({
    'background-color': '#000'
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HAZ3n/1/)

To change the inside div colors

```
 $( "#sortable .ui-state-default" ).css({
        'background': '#efefef'
    });
```

[Inner Div Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HAZ3n/10/)

Comment: my version = jQuery 1.9.1
jQuery UI 1.9.2

Comment: @STP38 the jquery used in fiddle is also the same and it works fine over there

Comment: This is wrong.  It should be `'background-color': '#000'` but you have `'background-color', '#000'`  (the comma is incorrect)

Comment: `$( "#sortable" ).css({'background-color', '#000'});` wrong syntax give `:` instead of `,`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct fiddle also with fixed span positioning.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/HAZ3n/7/

```
$( "#sortable .ui-state-default" ).css({
    background: '#000'
});
```